# I don't understand that part of code about recursive for generating subsets (java)

Tags: java

public List> subsets(int[] nums) {

```
List<List<Integer>> mr = new ArrayList<>();

    subset(nums, new ArrayList<>(), mr, 0);

    return mr;
}
```

------------>       EXPLAIN THIS FROM HERE WITH EXAMPLE {1,2,3}
    private void subset(int[] nums, List tempList, List> mr, int idx) {

```
    mr.add(new ArrayList<>(tempList));

    for (int i = idx; i < nums.length; i++) {

        tempList.add(nums[i]);

        subset(nums, tempList, mr, i + 1);
tempList.remove(tempList.size() - 1);
    }
```

Comment: no,    subset(nums, tempList, mr, i + 1); I don't understand this line this is soo weird to me

Comment: Your code does not compile because you are missing the tempList instantiation and the method parameters should be fixed. Can you update the question to fix that? Something regarding recursion in Java: it should be avoided because it reduces readability and tends to be a fountain of bugs (for instance stack overflow exceptions), but any method can call itself as long as there is a "exit point" (for instance iterating lists of lists till there is nothing more to iterate)